# Making a post request when there are no attributes in the form element?

Tags: python, html, forms, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm looping through zip codes and retrieving information from this site `http://www.airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=school_flag_program.sfp_createwidget`

Here's the form and input elements:

```
<form name="groovyform">
<input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" size="20" maxlength="20" />
<input type="text" name="Zipcode" id="Zipcode" size="10" maxlength="10" />
```

My question is how do I make a post request if there are no attributes in the form element (such as `action` or `method`)?

My code (I've tried `request.get` with the `params` argument, and `request.post` with the `data` argument):

```
url = 'http://www.airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=school_flag_program.sfp_createwidget'
data_to_send = {'zipcode ':'37217',
                'Title': 'ph'}
response = requests.get(url, params=data_to_send)
contents = response.text
print contents
```

just returns the HTML of the `url` but I want the HTML of the page I get when I post the `data`. In other words, I don't think `request.get` is submitting my data and I think it has something to do with there not being an `action` or `method` attribute.

Enlighten me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That form isn't intended to be submitted anywhere. It's just there for the benefit of the `Copy` button:

```
<input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="copy(document.groovyform.simba.value)" />
```

There are also a number of references to `document.groovyform` in the `buildCall` Javascript function, which is run when you click on `Build your widget`.

This is an old style of Javascript programming. These days, most would assign IDs to these elements, and use `document.getElementById()` to access them, so there would be no need to wrap them in a form. But before that approach was developed, the way to access DOM elements depended on the fact that forms are automatically added as properties of `document`, and input elements are properties of the containing form.

Answer (score 1):

Reading Comprehension, I could learn it.

Comment: Did you not read the whole post? Specifically this part: "I've tried request.get with the params argument, and request.post with the data argument."

Comment: No, I didn't see that, mostly because it's kinda asinine for you to be making a POST request and the code you provide is all GET requests. Doesn't make any sense to me. Why don't you edit your post with relevant code (i.e. using request.post) and the responses you get as well rather than just telling us 'returns some HTML'

Comment: From what I've researched, you don't always "post" data with the post function. For one example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557475/send-post-request-python. It depends on the `method` attribute.

Comment: You don't have a method attribute in the form here at all, so why would you default to GET? Either way, none of this is relevant and the other comment has the correct answer.

Comment: @LawrenceDeanVanderpool FYI, the default method is `GET`.

Comment: "You don't have a method attribute in the form." That's what I said. Why would I default to GET? Trial and error, my friend.

Comment: @Barmar the default method is get when you want to submit a post request including a form?

Comment: If a `<form>` doesn't have a `method` attribute, it will act as if you'd written `method="get"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so like Barmar stated, the `<form>` I posted isn't supposed to be submitted. The form I was supposed to be filling out (top of the page) contained the following:

```
<form name="frmZipSearch" method="get" style="width:178px; float:left;">
 Zip Code:
<input name="zipcode" type="text" size="5"  maxlength="5" height="20">
```

Now my code works.

```
url = 'http://www.airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=airnow.local_city&zipcode=37217&submit=Go'
data_to_send = {'zipcode':'37217'}
response = requests.get(url, data=data_to_send)
contents = response.text
print contents
```

Thanks, Barmar, for directing me to the right path.